# Get value of textbox in a table (GAS)

Tags: google-apps-script

I know that this is something discussed sooo many times, but I can't get the value of a textbox that is placed in a table. I know how to get the value of a textbox (e.parameter.textBoxName), usually it's working without any problems.

The only difference now is that I have a gadget containing 5 tabs, each with some intro text and a table. Each table contains approximately 30 rows, each with two textboxes and a button to submit the value of two textboxes in the specific row to a spreadsheet. Everything is working fine, all the names (and IDs as well) are unique, but the problem is that when I submit textboxes, I get "undefined" (in my spreadsheet).

I guess the problem lays somewhere in the complexity of the script, so this:

```
function buttonClick(e) {
    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    var theValue = e.parameter.textBoxName;
    ...something...
}
```

..is simply not enough to define which textbox it is. However I'm getting the button ID without any problem with

```
var buttId = new String(e.parameter.source);
```

I'm trying to get my head around this for a couple of days without any results. I'm not that good with GAS and I'm completely out when it comes to objective programming. Do you have some ideas how to get this value? I can get the ID of the table if that helps, but what to use then?

Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT:
I tried .addCallbackElement(textbox) to the textbox - I'm getting an error. I tried .addCallbackElement(textbox) to the submit button together with .addCallbackElement(button) and I'm still getting "undefined".

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried `.addCallBackElement(textBox)` as mentioned here [link](http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831385/google-apps-script-textbox-value-not-passed-to-e-parameter-textboxname?rq=1) but I'm getting an error, maybe I just don't know how to do it :-/.

Answer (score 0):

the callbackElement must be added **to the handler**, not to the widget nor to the button.

The easiest (and safest) way to get it done correctly is to choose the highest level parent as callbackElement.

I your case it would probably be the tab panel or eventually another panel that contains your 5 tabs if you used one.

Note also that there might be really **a lot** of widgets in the same UI without causing any issue... I have an app with about 200 textBoxes that works flawlessly and I'm not aware of any limit nor if a limit even exists...

Comment: thank you for your answer. Where should I place the code with callbackelement? I tried both tab panel and table and I still get "undefined".